# How can I set a grid with the value of my 2D array?(Java, Android Studio)

Tags: java, android

I have a school project, I have to build a Tetris Game. 
So I began with the creation of my menu with the different level, when I click on one level i go to my second activity (the game area) and I have also created my custom block.

My problem is a visual issue, indeed I don't know what type of layout I have to use for my surface game (gridlayout, linearlayout, grid etc. ...).

And then how to affect my blocks custom in this surface game, in this layout?

See the result expected.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c8Eu0.png)

Comment: Hello everybody (sorry the courtasy message wasn't send...)

Comment: With reference to the additional information you posted as an answer,  I think this makes the scope of the question a bit too broad I'm afraid. SO can help with specific coding issues, but not with wider aspects like game mechanics. Personally I'd look into tutorials on how to draw on canvas - if each block is the same size, you can calculate drawing positions based on the column and row information held in `myArrayGrid`

Comment: Also please take a few moments to read ["How do I ask a good question?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand what you want entirely but ill give it a shot from what i think you mean. 
You should use a nested for loop to do it, if your array was int[10,20](not right syntax but i cant be bothered to count the actual size of your array).
you should go:

(pseudocode)
also assume your resolution is 100, 200

```
    For(int i = 1 To 10){
      For(int k = 1 To 20){
        DrawSquare(i*10, k*10, "block type")
         k = k + 1
}
 i = i + 1
}
```

Then it will fill your 100, 200 area with the block type specified. Now if you want to load what block type you want freom the array you can just call the array in the block type.

```
 DrawSquare(i*10, k*10, Array[i,k])
```

Obviously bear in mind that its all pseudocode to display the logic.
Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Building on Valhalla's answer with a Java-specific example, it's still a bit unclear what you're asking, but assuming you want to initialise the grid to begin with you can use this code:

```
private final int columns = 10;
private final int rows = columns * 2;
private int[][] grid;

private void initialise() {
    grid = new int[columns][rows];
    for (int i = 0; i < columns; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < rows; j++) {
            grid[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

And assuming that you have a block that starts at the top, and falls one square with each iteration provided there's nothing underneath, you can try this:

```
private void blockFall() {
    // Start from 1 row above the bottom and parse upwards 
    // so a block won't drop right to the bottom on a single iteration
    for (int i = 0; i < columns; i++) {
        for(int j = rows - 2; j >= 0; j--) {
            if (grid[i][j] > 0 && grid[i][j+1] == 0) {
               grid[i][j+1] = grid[i][j];
               grid[i][j] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
 }
```